# The right way to use hyphenated attributes in haml.js

Tags: javascript, haml

For attributes like `<meta http-equiv=X-UA-Compatible`>

in Ruby haml:

I would use `%meta{:'http-equiv' => 'X-UA-Compatible'}`

it's not elegant, but works fine

today I'm using [haml.js](https://www.npmjs.org/package/hamljs)

it reports a a error

any idea?

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
%meta(http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge")
```